# Cycles of the big bang related to entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, entropy, space-expansion, big-bang

I recently watched this [video](https://youtu.be/DxL2HoqLbyA) about entropy by Veritaserum, and I've been thinking about the consequences of this in relation to the big bang and the most probable final stage of the universe (the cold death of the universe), and I've come up with some questions. So at the moment of the big bang, there was basically zero entropy. But when talking about time, many physicists say that the question "Was anything before the big bang?" is absolute nonsense. But has it something to do with the arrow of time linked with entropy so that there was no arrow of time before the big bang because there couldn't be lower entropy than zero? And as time passes, the most likely "end" of the universe is expected to be the cold death. But in the video, it is said that "we" won't be able to determine whether time is going forward or backward based on the behavior of the particles. But as we know, there is always a small chance that a less probable scenario will happen because the entropy of a system fluctuates. So is there a small chance that a new universe will be created? Because if you have as small a chance as you can imagine for one try, but you can have as many tries as you want, there is a 100% chance that the least probable scenario will happen (All the energy of the universe will be smacked into a singularity). And if this is true, then there will be an infinite number of cycles when a new universe is born. What do you think?